# Html/Js live update page

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am programming the website for my church hockey league, and I am trying to make a page with live updates. I am currently trying a `setInterval()` to signal php to update the time.txt which the live page can draw the time from. So the update.html has the time on it, this page sends the time to a php doc with a get function which writes the time to time.txt, then live.html gets the time every 5 secs with a `setInterval()`. In that 5 secs live.html keeps its own time, but needs to check every 5 for pauses or time changes.

The problem is this: the server cant handle updating time.txt every 2.5 seconds so I need a simpler method that doesn't require me to update time.txt every 2.5, but live.html still can get the time, pauses, and time changes.

Any help please.

Here is update.html

```
$('#play').click(function(){
    if(pause == true){
        $('#play').attr('src',"mup/pause.jpg");
        $.get("mup/postt.php", {text: "11"});
        pause = false;
    } else {
        $('#play').attr('src',"mup/play.jpg");
        $.get("mup/postt.php", {text: "09"});
        pause = true;
    }
});
function updatet(){
    if(sec < 10){
        if(min < 10){
            var clientmsg = "0" + min + ":0" + sec;
        } else {
            var clientmsg = min + ":0" + sec;
        }
    } else {
        if(min < 10){
            var clientmsg = "0" + min + ":" + sec;
        } else {
            var clientmsg = min + ":" + sec;
        }
    } 
    $.get("mup/postt.php", {text: clientmsg});
}
setInterval (timer, 1000);
setInterval (updatet, 3000);
```

all the variables are defined at the beginning of the doc.

here is live.html

```
function timer() {
    if(stop == true){
        $("#time").html("<h5>Game Stopped</h5>"); 
    } else {
        sec = sec-1;
        if(sec <= -1){
            sec = 59;
            min = min-1;
            if(min <= -1){
                sec=0;
                min=0;
            }
        }
        $("#time").html("\<h2\>"+min+":"+sec+"\</h2\>");
    }
}
loadLog() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "mup/time.txt",
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            var min = html.charAt(0).concat(html.charAt(1));
            var sec = html.charAt(3).concat(html.charAt(4));
            var time = min + ":" + sec;
            if(time == timel){
                stop = true;
            } else {
                stop = false;
            }
            timel = time;
        },
    });
}
setInterval (loadLog, 5000);
setInterval (timer, 1000);
```

and at the beginning of the doc all variable were defined with timel and time being different. Post.php just puts the sent stuff onto the doc, so time.txt would look like "06:08" or whatever.aa

Comment: use ajax with jquery or without jquery

Comment: You can't _talk about_ code and expect help. You have to show it.

Comment: I am using jquery, and I need a better method that doesnt tax the server. One sec on that code, sorry.

Comment: No database just text docs. To use a database would tax the server even more and I'm trying not to.

Comment: So don't put the database on your server. Get a CouchDB instance at http://www.iriscouch.com/ and use AJAX to achieve this effect. Writing to the file system of a machine that you are concerned can't write to a database is probably not a good idea. Host the DB somewhere that has the capacity for it. Using a txt file as a database is not okay in production, even jesus won't forgive you for that

Comment: Oh its a problem because of a 304 error the browser gets when sending the request for post.php, I looked it up and guessed that the server cant update the file that often, if this isn't the reason for the 304 please tell me.

Comment: Iris Couch offers a free CouchDB instance, and, based on the data in your code it looks like privacy is not a concern (someone looking at it would just say, wtf). Just FYI, honestly the writing to a text file thing is going to give you more headaches in the long run than you really want - it's a debugging nightmare, for example.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Check out the formatting tips for how to separate code blocks from just plain text. Also, your loadLog function is missing the `function` keyword.

Comment: Oh, Couch is free, I'll try that now.

Comment: http://guide.couchdb.org/editions/1/en/tour.html as a good resource if you decide to use it.

Comment: @phatskat Thankyou, and I'll check that.

Comment: Have you heard of websockets for doing such kind of things?

Comment: This looks like its gonna work. Thank you all.

Comment: @Saurabh it looks like I could use that, but I have no idea how and what I am currently doing looks like its gonna work.

Comment: If you want to skip the todo yourself part. Try using https://www.firebase.com/ quick and simple.

Comment: @Saurabh that looks like it'll work as well, I'll try both and see which I like better.